# How to open the email inbox view in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

As per my requirement, on click of button, I need to open the mail clients which are available in my device. once the user selects particular mail client,I need to show his inbox and he can select the particular email and he can send that email.

**To open email clients i have used this particular code:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "abc@xyz.com" });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

once the mail clients opens, I need to select any particular mail client and it should take me to that particular application inbox, i can select any mail and need to send.

could any body help me out how to solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just let android choose the appropriate app.  The user might have an app they saved as their default app to open mail in. why make them choose every time?

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

> once the user selects particular mail client,I need to show his inbox

There is no standard `Intent` structure for showing an email inbox. There are many, many email apps for Android, each of which can do this however they wish.

The best you can hope to do is:

- Create an `ACTION_SENDTO` `Intent` with a `mailto:` `Uri`
- Use that `Intent` with `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to find all activities that support this, and hope that they are actually from email clients
- Find out the applications associated with those activities, from the `ResolveInfo` you get back from `queryIntentActivities()`
- Use `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` on `PackageManager` to find some likely "front door" activity for each of the applications
- Create your own chooser-style dialog to allow the user to choose one of those applications
- Call `startActivity()` on the `Intent` they chose

However:

- This may include non-email apps, as I am welcome to write an app that offers to support `mailto:` `Uri` values with `ACTION_SENDTO`
- The "front door" activities of these apps are not necessarily the inbox

> he can select the particular email and he can send that email

I have no idea what this means.

> To open email clients i have used this particular code

Note that your code has two flaws:

1. You are using an invalid MIME type (plain text is `text/plain`, not `plain/text`)
2. You are not supplying a prompt for the chooser

Comment: Hey I dint get exactly what you mentioned here, can you please post some sample so that i can get better idea, I was stuck in getting the packagename ......intent sendIntent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.application.abc");  I used the mentioned code to get package related info but i am not getting anything, could you please post the sample how to continue on this. I have seen launchalot code, but there we are displaying all the applications, i want only email clients to be open, do the needful  thanks.