# access to any email inbox from my activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

As we use "content://sms/inbox" for sms inbox, do we have anything like this for email.I want to read email from after selecting email client.I tried the following the code

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");

    Uri data = Uri.parse("content://mail/inbox");
    intent.setData(data);
    startactivity(intent);
```

I dont want to send mail,just to read the mail,So i cant use mailto:

Comment: So you want to open the email app , using that intent?

Comment: Yes, What should I write instead of "content://mail/inbox".?

Answer (score 1):

You should use this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    Intent mailer = Intent.createChooser(intent, null);
    startActivity(mailer);
```

Comment: But by using this i will be restricted to only gmail app, what if there is another app like hotmail.?

Comment: Thank you, but this starts activity to compose mail and not to the inbox.

Comment: Sorry aparrently you want this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435883/how-to-open-the-email-inbox-view-in-android , take a look there

Comment: I think it is not possible in android to open inbox of any email client.Thank you for the help